# Spring Redis save POJO as different types when using @Cacheable or @CachePut

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, spring-cache

I have students which I would like to save both in DB and in Redis cache for improving performance.

I have the Student POJO:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@RedisHash("Student")
public class Student implements Serializable, RedisElement {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4555735174035964832L;
    public enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Gender gender;
    private int grade;

}
```

Used in `StudentRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, String>{

}
```

I have service which can add, find and delete student:

```
@Service
public class StudentsService {
    @Cacheable(value = "Student", key = "#id")
    public Student findById(String id) {
        // simulates getting it from db
        Student studentFromDB = Student.builder().id(id).name("db user " + id)
                    .gender((new Random()).nextDouble() > 0.5 ? Gender.FEMALE : Gender.MALE)
                    .grade((new Random()).nextInt(100)).build();
            return studentFromDB;// will be cached next time
    }
    
    @CachePut(value = "Student", key = "#id")
    public Student add(Student student) {
        System.out.println("added student " + student);
        return student;
    }
}
```

Running my application with `RedisApplication`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class RedisApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RedisApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Whenever I call explicitly to the `studentrepository.save(student)` method , it calls Redis HMSET and SADD commands to add the student to the cache, but when I use Spring `@Cachaeble` to do that, it uses the Redis Set command to add the student.

How can I configure `@Cachaeble` or `@CachePut` to treat student object the way that calling explicitly will use the Redis HMSET and SADD commands?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, I am afraid that the implementation of the cache mechanism is tightly coupled in the library.

All the actual interactions with Redis are performed by [`DefaultRedisCacheWriter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/4dcb2157988bd2e65e4d9ebced53836f73582d0b/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java) which is package scoped.

The following code is the one corresponding to the put (cache) operation.

As described in the [Spring Data Redis documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:support:cache-abstraction), probably the way to go will be providing your own [`RedisCacheWriter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/4dcb2157988bd2e65e4d9ebced53836f73582d0b/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheWriter.java), I assume based on `DefaultRedisCacheWriter` with the necessary modifications, and configure Spring cache `RedisCacheManager` appropriately:

```java
RedisCacheWriter cacheWriter = // Provide your custom implementation...
RedisCacheManager cm = RedisCacheManager.build(cacheWriter)
    .cacheDefaults(defaultCacheConfig())
    ...
```